# ASP.NET Core constant requests to home controller

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, request, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2016

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application hosted on Google Compute Engine, and when I check the logs, it seems that `www.mysite.com/home/index` is constantly being requested even though I am not searching that URL in my browser and nobody else knows the actual URL. Why is this? I am concerned that it may be interfering with some of my processes.

I am running the app on Windows Server 2016 and I often Remote Desktop into it. Could either of these be the reason behind the logs I am getting?

```
{"@t":"2019-01-01T09:37:24.4301536Z","@m":"Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.142.0.4/  ","@i":"ca22a1cb","Protocol":"HTTP/1.1","Method":"GET","ContentType":null,"ContentLength":null,"Scheme":"http","Host":"10.142.0.4","PathBase":"","Path":"/","QueryString":"","HostingRequestStartingLog":"Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.142.0.4/  ","EventId":{"Id":1},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost","RequestId":"0HLJFPIU5NJ9V:00000001","RequestPath":"/","CorrelationId":null,"ConnectionId":"0HLJFPIU5NJ9V"}
{"@t":"2019-01-01T09:37:24.5299320Z","@m":"Route matched with \"{action = \\\"Index\\\", controller = \\\"Home\\\"}\". Executing action \"TelebotApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TelebotApplication)\"","@i":"a44c0341","RouteData":"{action = \"Index\", controller = \"Home\"}","ActionName":"TelebotApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TelebotApplication)","EventId":{"Id":1},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker","ActionId":"dc996f72-2933-4b90-9a5e-ccbfe11d91ba","RequestId":"0HLJFPIU5NJ9V:00000001","RequestPath":"/","CorrelationId":null,"ConnectionId":"0HLJFPIU5NJ9V"}
{"@t":"2019-01-01T09:37:24.5405482Z","@m":"Executing action method \"TelebotApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TelebotApplication)\" - Validation state: Valid","@i":"dad538d7","ActionName":"TelebotApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TelebotApplication)","ValidationState":"Valid","EventId":{"Id":1},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker","ActionId":"dc996f72-2933-4b90-9a5e-ccbfe11d91ba","RequestId":"0HLJFPIU5NJ9V:00000001","RequestPath":"/","CorrelationId":null,"ConnectionId":"0HLJFPIU5NJ9V"}
{"@t":"2019-01-01T09:37:24.5441766Z","@m":"Executed action method \"TelebotApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TelebotApplication)\", returned result \"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult\" in 0.4835ms.","@i":"50a9e262","ActionName":"TelebotApplication.Controllers.HomeController.Index (TelebotApplication)","ActionResult":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult","ElapsedMilliseconds":0.48350000000000004,"EventId":{"Id":2},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker","ActionId":"dc996f72-2933-4b90-9a5e-ccbfe11d91ba","RequestId":"0HLJFPIU5NJ9V:00000001","RequestPath":"/","CorrelationId":null,"ConnectionId":"0HLJFPIU5NJ9V"}
```

This seems to pretty much repeat itself endlessly.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share us your `Startup.cs`? Have you enabled any `Healthy Check Feature` for your project? Check whether there is any value for `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;`. Try to comment out `Home/Index` Code to check whether will throw any error without explicty request this address.

Comment: Ahhh. My healthchecks. Of course, that would be it. Whilst a healthcheck is running, is it possible that it interferes with traffic other traffic on the same port?

Comment: Do you mean your issue is caused by healthchecks? How did you configure your healthchecks? In general, it would not causes  performance issue.

Comment: I configured them in the GCP console. I will get some more information regarding them. The issue I am facing, is occassionally, `public static void Main(string[] args)` is re-entered without my instruction. So I am thinking that a failed healthcheck may cause this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I check the logs, it seems that www.mysite.com/home/index is constantly being requested even though I am not searching that URL in my browser and nobody else knows the actual URL

For this issue, it is caused by [Health checking](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/how-instances-are-managed) you configured in the GCP.

> The issue I am facing, is occassionally, public static void
>   Main(string[] args) is re-entered without my instruction.

For this issue, it is usually caused by the application recycling. Exceptions in request would not make application recycling.

Comment: Thank you, this is nice and concise. So, I am gathering that the application recycling is independent of the health checks and therefore, how can I control this recycling or what causes it to occur? It appears to disrupt my code, particularly anything involving an active websocket or RPC call.

Comment: @HarryStuart For `IIS`, it is controlled by IIS, for GCP, I am afriad you need to confrim with `google-compute-engine`.